# $\int-t \ \tan(\ln(t)) dt$

Tags: integration

I have been scouring the internet for ideas on how to attack this problem, but come up with nothing. I tried u-substitution and integration by parts, but I keep ending up in loops. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any context for this problem? As it stands to reason, this integral shouldn't have a "nice and simple" closed form. You can expand it as an infinite sum and rewrite the result in terms of the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Submit it to Wolfram Alpha...

Comment: Are there bounds?

Comment: What happened to the question?